# How do I use Chrome workspaces with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to use it to mostly be able to edit and save CSS. However, how do I link `application.css?body=1` to the CSS file `assets/stylesheets/application.css`?

I've added the `assets` and project root directory to the Workspaces, but they don't seem to recognize the CSS file with a generated relative path.

If anyone has done this before and has any input, that would be great. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, this is not supported just yet. Please file a feature request at http://crbug.com/new

Comment: That's unfortunate, I'll definitely do that thanks for the heads up.